# have a variable stored with few values and need to grep lines with particular word "yes" after first occurrence of a particular word "End"

Tags: awk, sed, grep

have a variable stored with few values and need to grep lines with particular word "yes". But need to grep only after first occurrence of a particular word for example "End"

Consider below variable value which has below lines

```
one
two
three          yes
------End------
wind
tree
fruits         yes 
------End------
hi
hello         yes
```

from the variable, need to grep all lines that has "yes" after first occurrence of word End

Expected output:

```
fruits         yes
hello         yes
```

Comment: i only know how to grep all lines after match in a file but not sure how to grep all lines after first occurrence of matching word in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed -n '/End/,${/yes/p}' file 
fruits         yes
hello         yes
```

If you have the data in a variable:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$variable" | sed -n '/End/,${/yes/p}'
fruits         yes
hello         yes
```

To save *that* in a variable:

```
$ new_variable=$(printf '%s\n' "$variable" | sed -n '/End/,${/yes/p}')
```

The `sed` script will print all lines containing the string `yes` (with `/yes/p`), but only from those lines that come after the first occurrence of the word `End` (in the range `/End/,$`, i.e. from the line that contains `End` to the end).

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '/End/{p=1}p==1&&/yes/' file
fruits         yes 
hello         yes
```

Explained:

```
awk '
/End/ { p=1 }  # the End set p flag to 1
p==1 && /yes/  # when p flag raised and at yes, output
' file
```

If you'd like to print after the second `End` change `p=1` to `p++` and the comparison `p==1` to `p>=2`.

Comment: need to grep from variable and not from a file...can you guide me in using the command with respect to variable instead of file

Comment: `echo "$var" | awk ...`